# Which race in Star Trek universe was the first to invent Warp technology?

Tags: star-trek, ftl-drive, warp

Humans look like late member of Warp Drive community. Klingons were capable of interstellar travel from the time of Kahless. Vulcans were in contact with Andorians from ancient times (ST: Enterprise).

Which one first invented warp capabilities: Klingons or Vulcans? Or, others?

Comment: Perhaps warp drive was invented more than once by the vulcans, in the same was that different cultures invented the same things on Earth but at different time periods (can't recall specifics but I'm pretty sure there are some - someone want to help me out?). Just a thought.

Comment: I read once that in an early encounter between the Kligons and Romulans the Klingons exchanged their Warp technology against the Romulan cloak. So the Klingons had Warp before the Romulans.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: If I recall, the Klingons actually traded starship designs for the cloak, not warp technology. Romulan ships were large and blulky before the trade, but were more streamlined and more avian-like afterwards (akin to Klingon design). However, I have no idea what difference the changes in design made for the efficiency/effectiveness of their ships.

Comment: The Preservers? Iconians?

Comment: My answer to this question  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220439/which-humanoid-race-was-the-first-warp-capable-species/220461#220461  claims that it is unanswerable.  But it does suggest a possible answer to the question which warp capable and still active species known to the Federation was considered the oldest at one era of Federation history.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Technically the first race to discover warp drive would be the ancient race in [*The Chase*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Chase) in *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.  This is the species that moved out into the galaxy, explored it, and found it empty, so they seeded planets with DNA (which also explains why there are so many humanoid races in the galaxy).

But if you're talking races that are currently active on an interstellar scale, according to [Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.org/), here's a simple table taken from the article on [warp drive](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Warp_drive):

Vulcans: 9th century B.C.
Romulans: Didn't split from Vulcans until after Warp Drive.
Klingons: 9th century A.D.
Vissians: 12th century A.D.
Borg: 15th century A.D.
Humans: 21st century A.D.

(**Note: Changes since original posting!** The Memory Alpha article is confusing, one way it can be read is that Vulcans had an interstellar civilization in the 9th century B.C., but still didn't have warp drive until after A.D. 1947.  It also took Vulcans a century to go from breaking lightspeed to reaching speeds as fast as warp 2.)

Data on other races and when they developed warp drive is apparently not available.

Comment: Do you know the name of ancient race in The Chase in Star Trek: The Next Generation??

Comment: And, what about Andorians?

Comment: The "seeding" race in ST:TNG was never given a species name.  I couldn't find anything specifying when the Andorians developed warp drive.

Comment: The Romulans didn't depart Vulcan until the [4th century A.D.](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/4th_century), so they always had warp drive.

Comment: @TangoOversway Unless you have a source I don't know about, the Borg were _at least_ as far back as 1484, at which point they were already spacefaring.  We don't know an actual date for them.  A bit nitpicky, but when we don't know...  ;)

Comment: @Izkata: I cited my source in the answer.  It's memory Alpha.  I'm adding the link to the actual article now.  I'm just pulling from there as a main source because I can't keep up with all the books and other materials.

Comment: @TangoOversway Yeah, in Dragon's Teeth the Vaadwaur said the Borg already controlled a few systems by that time (also mentioned in the Borg article, History section)

Comment: @Izkata: I wonder why they didn't include that in the article.

Comment: @SachinShekhar There is speculation that the ancient race is the [Preservers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preservers_(Star_Trek)#Preservers)

Comment: @WesleyWiser For some reason, until now I was certain that they were called the Progenitors. Even the Memory Alpha article hints that one may have been confused with the other. Not sure how or why.

Comment: _Borg: 15th century A.D_ I thought a human invented the Borg? Or am I insane?

Comment: @Daft; I don't know the answer to you question, though from what I remember  I doubt it.  But....even if you are wrong about that, it does not imply that you are insane.

Comment: My answer to this question https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220439/which-humanoid-race-was-the-first-warp-capable-species/220461#220461claims that it is unanswerable. But it does suggest a possible answer to the question which warp capable and still active species known to the Federation was considered the oldest at one era of Federation history.  And I consider the list of dates in Memory Alpha to  be making a number of unjustified assumptions.